# Python 2.7.11 Turtle Graphics Crashing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I made this code in Python 2.7.11, using turtle graphics:

```
import turtle

previousMovement = ""
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("white")
player.shape("triangle")
player.pencolor("red")

speed = 1

def left():
    global previousMovement
    if previousMovement == "left":
        player.forward(speed)
        previousMovement = "left"
    else:
        player.head(90)
        player.forward(speed)
        previousMovement = "left"

def right():
    global previousMovement
    if previousMovement == "right":
        player.forward(speed)
        previousMovement = "right"
    else:
        player.head(270)
        player.forward(speed)
        previousMovement = "right"


turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(left, "a")
turtle.onkey(right, "d")
```

It's pretty simple at the moment but whenever I try to run it, the Python Turtle Graphics window will come up and then everything will pause and then it will say "Not Responding" and close. Is there something in my code which is causing that or is it another problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try entering the turtle mainloop:

```
# other code...
turtle.onkey(right, "d")
turtle.mainloop()
```

I also find that turtle needs `.setheading(270)` instead of `.head(270)`. You'll probably need to change your other one as well.